# How to add process as a relation in database e.g record of donation etc

Tags: mysql, sql, database, model, erd

[image]

> I wanted to record processes of donating blood by a donor to a blood bank as well as processes of accepting blood by a patient from a blood bank by including table of the processes
>
> record of Donation and record of Acceptance
>
> I was confused on how to add the tables should i link them with the donors or the bank can i get help with plus any other additional info i will grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I totally understand the image you posted, but based on your explanation, here is a sample design for your use case.

1) Start with the following 3 tables : they define the base objects, and are independant one from the other.

```
DONOR
    ID               -- primary key
    NAME
    BLOOD_GROUP
    MEDICAL_REPORT
    CONTACT_NUMBER
    ADDRESS

PATIENT
    ID               -- primary key
    NAME
    BLOOD_GROUP
    DISEASE

BLOOD_BANK
    ID               -- primary key
    ADDRESS
    CONTACT_NUMBER
```

Now you are ready to create tables that keep track of the Donations and Acceptances.

2) The Donation table references the Donor and the Blood Bank :

```
DONATION
    ID               -- primary key
    DONOR_ID         -- foreign key to DONOR.ID
    BLOOD_BANK_ID    -- foreign key to BLOOD_BANK.ID
    PLACE
    TIME
    AMOUNT
```

3) The Acceptance table references the Donation and the Patient :

```
 ACCEPTANCE
    ID               -- primary key
    PATIENT_ID       -- foreign key to PATIENT.ID
    DONATION_ID      -- foreign key to DONATION.ID
```